# Is @TargetApi annotation just for one Api level or above?

Tags: android

I am using @TargetApi(23) in my app.

```
@TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        onAttachToContext(context);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            onAttachToContext(activity);
        }
    }

    protected void onAttachToContext(Context context) {

    }
```

But i can not understand something: @TargetApi(23) annotation's mean "just for Api level 23" or "for Api level 23 and above" ? For example if Api level of device 24, is onAttach(Context context) method called?

Comment: `@TargetApi(23)` means "I, as the author of this method, will ensure that it is never called on API Level 24 or higher. However, I have tested it and feel that it works correctly for API Level 23 and below, even though my `minSdkVersion` is below 23." Your use of `@TargetApi` has no affect on Android itself and whether or not the method is called. It merely tells the build tools to stop complaining about problems that you feel you are handling correctly.

Comment: @CommonsWare Isn't that the exact wrong way around?

Comment: @Liminal: I do not know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Doesn't @TargetApi(23) mean you guarantee it will never be called on API Level 22 or lower, not 24 or higher?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, you are correct, I had that comment wrong. My apologies!

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a reason you have not updated your first comment according to Liminal's correction? :)

Comment: @kuhr: Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes, and the correction came nearly three years too late for that. I left the original comment there so the rest of the comments make sense. And, if your :) meant that you knew all of that, my apologies for stacksplaining! (or is that overflowsplaining?)

Comment: Haha, didn't know about the 5 minutes limit. And I also didn't know about the word "overflowsplaining". So all in all your answer was just 10/10! :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[TargetApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html) annotation is just for lint tool purposes and has no outcome in runtime. If you use any API methods just available on 23 within your method and don't declare the TargetApi, you will just get some warnings indicating you're using API's not available in your minimum SDK version. It's your responsibility to call this method with coherence being aware of the API level it will be called from.

Comment: So if I run a method of @TargetApi(26) on a, say, API 13 system, nothing will just simply crash right? (As long as I only conditionally execute the certain statements which require higher API)

Answer (score 8):

@TargetApi does not prevent any code from running, 
all it does is to remove lint errors.

You still need to add something along the lines of

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    //to do something
}else{
    //to do something else
}
```

I upgraded @Yang's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
```

which denotes that the annotated element should only be called on the given API level or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Fivos answer, adding @RequiresApi also means that there will be a build/compile error showing that you are calling a method/functionality that only exists on a target higher than the minimum target you have specified.

[Function using @requiresapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5wY9.png)

[Compilation error after adding requires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdagv.png)