# what is android @TargetApi annotations means

Tags: android, annotations

does TargetApi mean that code must be called under a specific version or 
must be called greater than or equal specific version?for example

TargetApi(23) means that use for (23 and below ) or (23 and above)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is @TargetApi annotation just for one Api level or above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825725/is-targetapi-annotation-just-for-one-api-level-or-above)

Answer (score 3):

Target Api 23 means that the annotated method should run only on api 23+ devices. You should use it with IF check for api level of the device. If your app's minimum api level is lower than 23 consider providing a method for older devices.

Comment: so we can say that it is same with requiresApi ?

Comment: Not exactly. As commented below, the annotation will remove the red underline of error, but You still should check api level runtime

Answer (score 1):

From [`TargetApi` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi):

> Indicates that Lint should treat this type as targeting a given API level, no matter what the project target is.

It's used purely for the linter. Instead of using `targetSdkVersion` specified in your `build.gradle`, it will use this API.

**When should you use this?**

Perhaps when you're using a deprecated API, but you don't want the linter to continue warning you. You explicitly tell the linter, I know that this is deprecated but I don't care, I am using it as if I was on an older API level. You might (should) also add a comment nearby.